# getting starting address of a stack in assembly programming

Tags: assembly, stack, masm

is it possible to get the effective starting address of a stack after completing stack operations like push and pop in assembly programming?

Comment: Do you mean starting address (i.e. base address, which doesn't change) or do you really mean the address of the top of the stack, i.e. the current value of the stack pointer ?

Comment: the starting base address...even top of stack will do..but prefrably base address

Comment: Base address doesn't change - this is there the stack pointer starts out at the beginning of your program. The top of stack address is what changes when you push/pop. Which one do you actually want ?

Comment: suppose i have performed some push pop operations and now i want to get the BOTTOM of the stack is it possible without popping all other values?

Comment: As @drlazy says below, you can just save the initial stack pointer at the start of your program, before you start pushing stuff onto the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention is to save (E)SP to (E)BP in the beginning of your function, and use (E)BP for local variable addressing.

Answer (score 0):

simplest case is just to save initial stack pointer to some variable to access it when needed. If it not the case, use platform specific API, for example VirtualQuery on Windows, using current SP value as first parameter. base address will be in BaseAddress field of MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION structure. On posix task can be done using pthread functions